# How many intersections of two functions with the same monotonicity?

Tags: calculus, functions, elementary-functions

For example, consider two functions monotonically increasing (when they have at least one intersection) in a particular interval，how many intersections do they have? Which factor may influence the number of intersection?
What if I add the condition that one's value includes the other's?
Meanwhile, I also wonder if there's a rule to determine whether two monotonically increasing functions with one's value including the other have only 1 intersection points?
Does this related to derivatives or concavity, or there just don't have a rule?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: If the function $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing, consider $g(x)=f(x)+a\sin(bx)$. You can increase $b$ to increase the number of intersections that $f$ and $g$ have within any interval, and then let $a$ be small enough to make $g$ an increasing function.